# FTP/IIS Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp, process

In IIS 7.5 When trying to get current log files using CMD FTP client it gives error

550 error: "The file cannot be accessed because it is in use by another process"

Checked processes using procmon and found that FTP was the only thing accessing it. Port 21 isn't being used by anything else either.

This Thread http://forums.iis.net/p/1169427/2043422.aspx/1?Re+FTP+550+The+process+cannot+access+the+file+because+it+is+being+used+by+another+process+

and this http://forums.iis.net/p/1173143/2043423.aspx/1?Re+FTP+7+5+550+Error

are the same issue I am having.
I have tried all the suggested fixes (Stopping services / process and restarting, creating user, giving user full rights to nfsw & FTP site, and allowing read file while uploading)

It seems something is locking the file and won't let me access it via FTP.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I think I found part of the problem. Windows FTP tries to Read/Write when accessing any file? I'm not sure how accurate this is but I'm wondering if there is a way to force windows FTP to only read so it can still access the current log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

IIS locks the ability to read/write to the current log file.

For some reason FTP (even if just using the get command) is see as reading/writing to the file. Which eliminates the ability to be able to use any kind of FTP (Like we were doing in web trends) to access those logs. What I ended up doing was sharing the log folder directory and accessing in via a network shared drive. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Check you log rolling setup.  The active log is always locked for writing by IIS (well, the WWW Publishing Service part anyway).  If you roll your logs frequently enough, you'll be able to gather the inactive ones easily enough.

Comment: We do a daily log. I can understand it being locked for writing but I'm just trying to read via FTP.