# Windows Server 2012 The process cannot access the file

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

I've FTP Server running on Windows Server 2012. FTP version is 8.0.9200.16384
In advanced settings for FTP under IIS, Allow Reading Files While Uploading is set to true and server is restarted. But still client is getting following error

550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

If the file is being used.  Any guidance on something I'm missing or some option has to be added

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the file being accessed by the client?

Comment: This error could also mean the port is in use. http://goo.gl/ho27vX

Comment: Client is trying to get the file by FTP.

Comment: @CIA it seems there was an issue in FTP 7.5  .  Not sure whether it is fixed  in 8.092 http://forums.iis.net/t/1159198.aspx?FTP+7+5+Cannot+access+file+while+in+use

Comment: The "Allow Reading Files While Uploading" setting only applies to files that are being uploaded via FTP to be read before the upload completes, not allow reading files that are open for writing by another application/process on the host, such as is often the case with log files/files being modified by the host. Is this not the case you're running into?

Comment: @austinian you are right. The client is trying to get the files being written by another process.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be either a design decision or a bug in IIS 7+, see this similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/481270/ftp-iis-error-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-an

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a limitation in IIS versions 7+. (According to [this forum post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1169427.aspx?FTP%20550%20The%20process%20cannot%20access%20the%20file%20because%20it%20is%20being%20used%20by%20another%20process%20), this wasn't a limitation in IIS 5.) I can't find official support for this claim, but I do see that some software vendors have circumvented this issue by ignoring these errors (and sometimes retrying later), [example here](https://getsatisfaction.com/weblogexpert/topics/iis_7_550_the_process_cannot_access_the_file_because_it_is_being_used_by_another_process) and some users have gotten around this by using methods other than direct FTP access, either by copying the file and then using FTP, or using a different file access protocol, such as what happened [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/481270/ftp-iis-error-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-an).